# Passing a variable into javascript, codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, datatables

I am not able to pass a variable from Codeigniter's view to controller and then model that shoots the query that is required to fetch the data from database.

here's my Controller(snippet):

```
public function read() {
        echo json_encode( $this->random_model->getAll() );
}
```

Model:

```
 public function getAll() {

    $id = $this->input->post('id');
            $id = intval( $id );
   // print_r($sg_id);

  //  var_dump($sg_id);


    $query = $this->db->where('id',$id)->limit( 100 )->get( 'table_name' );



    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

I'm sending the "$id" from another function :

```
function test1()
{

    $blaa['id'] = $this->input->post('id');

    if ($query = $this->model_name->getAll($blaa)) 
    {
        $blaa['records'] = $query;
    }

    //$this->model_name->getAll($blaa);
    $this->load->view('view_name', $blaa);

}
```

this is the test1 view:

```
<?php $attributes = array("class" => "", "id" => "", "name" => "");

   echo form_open("test/test1/", $attributes);?>

<input type="text" id="id" name="id" >

<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit')?>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

this is the view_name that shows all the data, I'm using dataTables.:

All.js that is rendered in the view_name (read data snippet):

```
var readUrl   = 'index.php/controller_name/read'

function readUsers() {
//display ajax loader animation
$( '#ajaxLoadAni' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );

$.ajax({
    url: readUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( response ) {

        for( var i in response ) {
            response[ i ].updateLink = updateUrl + '/' + response[ i ].id;
            response[ i ].deleteLink = delUrl + '/' + response[ i ].id;
        }

        //clear old rows
        $( '#records > tbody' ).html( '' );

        //append new rows
        $( '#readTemplate' ).render( response ).appendTo( "#records > tbody" );

        //apply dataTable to #records table and save its object in dataTable variable
        if( typeof dataTable == 'undefined' )
            dataTable = $( '#records' ).dataTable({"bJQueryUI": true});

        //hide ajax loader animation here...
        $( '#ajaxLoadAni' ).fadeOut( 'slow' );
    }
});
```

The results that I get are only of the data having the id "0" , no matter which value I send through the test controller.

Comment: in ajax you are not passing the value..

Answer (score 0):

add the id you want to `post` in `ajax` like this, Then you can use `$this->input->post("id");` in model or controller.

```
$.ajax({
    url: readUrl,
     data:{id: id which you want to pass.}
    dataType: 'json',// change this to post
    success: function( response ) {

    }
});
```

Comment: i'm still getting the data that only has "0" as id

Comment: in your code `data:{id: id which you want to pass.}` I tried to send a default value like `data:{id: 2}` still no luck

Comment: you are using json, change that to POST

Comment: it keeps on loading if I change that to POST

Comment: post should work because, you are capturing the value from post. Just refresh the page and try again.

Comment: try deep refresh and try once. may be because of cache.

Comment: tried on different browser. Same, keeps on loading.

Comment: wait i ll give some demo link, it might help you.

Comment: in controller try printing the post values

Comment: also see this http://www.technicalkeeda.com/details/simple-ajax-post-example-with-php-codeIgniter-framework-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Change your model code to this :

```
 public function getAll($id = null) {
    if ($id == null)
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $id = intval( $id );
   // print_r($sg_id);

  //  var_dump($sg_id);


    $query = $this->db->where('id',$id)->limit( 100 )->get( 'table_name' );



    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm still getting the data that only has "0" as id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getAll(id)
    {

        var id = id;

        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('controllerName/getAll');?>/"+id,
            success:function(data)
            {

            alert(data);

            }

            });
        }


<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getAll(1)"  title="Delete" class="icon-2 info-tooltip">Get All</a>
```

In your controller try to fetch id like this

```
public function getAll($id)
{

  echo $id;
}
```

for more try this : http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Comment: i'm still getting the data that only has "0" as id

Comment: i can't echo that in controller because the data is fetched by datatables.js and it will keep on loading since `echo $id;` is not supported by it.

Comment: Okay try this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/ everything is explained in details with datatable

Comment: the thing is I can get all the data if i don't pass my own `$id` but I want only the data with a specific id.

Comment: for that you need to save the id in getAll onclick function like this onclick="getAll('your id goes here')"